# Linux df command returns permission denied

Tags: linux, centos, df

Any ideas on how I can fix this, Im not sure it should return those results anyway...

```
$ df
df: `/var/named/chroot/etc/named': Permission denied
df: `/var/named/chroot/var/named': Permission denied
df: `/var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf': Permission denied
df: `/var/named/chroot/etc/named.rfc1912.zones': Permission denied
df: `/var/named/chroot/etc/rndc.key': Permission denied
df: `/var/named/chroot/usr/lib64/bind': Permission denied
df: `/var/named/chroot/etc/named.iscdlv.key': Permission denied
df: `/var/named/chroot/etc/named.root.key': Permission denied
df: `/var/named/chroot/etc/services': Permission denied
df: `/var/named/chroot/etc/protocols': Permission denied
df: `/var/named/chroot/lib64/libnss_files.so.2': Permission denied
Filesystem      1K-blocks     Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20511356   877116   18569280   5% /
devtmpfs          8157848      216    8157632   1% /dev
/dev/sda2      1901565084 10598976 1794349100   1% /home
tmpfs             8159952        0    8159952   0% /dev/shm
```

Comment: Try `sudo df` if you can.

Comment: when I sudo, it lists it /dev/root        20511356   878788   18567608   5% /var/named/chroot/etc/named

Comment: What about `sudo su` first and then next after that `cd /root` and then try `df` and see what your result is?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `df` was aliased, so you can try:

```
$ unalias df
$ df
```